# When did GB acknowledge the USA as sovereign state?

Tags: united-states, nation-states, great-britain

In which year did Great Britain acknowledge the independence of the USA and threat it like a sovereign country?

Comment: Have you tried reseaching this yourself?

Comment: Can you clarify the question and explain why the [Treaty of Paris](http://www.history.com/topics/american-revolution/treaty-of-paris) doesn't answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

In 1783.

Specifically, with the signing of the [Treaty of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Paris_(1783)) on 3 September 1783.

Interestingly, as the Wikipedia article notes, Article 1 of the treaty, in which King George III acknowledged the United States' existence as "free sovereign and independent states", is the only part of the treaty that remains in force.

Comment: Does GB really still consider the US to consist of 50 (or 13) separate "free sovereign and independent state*s*"?